# Emacs Starter Kit Mac Not Installing

Tags: emacs, starter-kits

I'm trying to install this:

https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit

I put the following into my ~/.emacs.d/init.el file:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

I then go to run M-x eval-buffer and am told "Cannot open load file: package"

Any idea how I can get around this? I'm unsure what's wrong, but for what it's worth, there was previously no init.el file and my .emacs file doesnt exist either.

Comment: `package.el` is part of Emacs 24. If you're using Emacs 23 or earlier it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The package.el used by emacs-starter-kit is for emacs 24.

There's the package.el file available for the emacs 23 :
 [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=blob_plain;hb=ba08b24186711eaeb3748f3d1f23e2c2d9ed0d09;f=lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el)

You should replace the package.el file